# Brooks' theorem and greedy algorithm-vertex colouring

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

[image]

For this question in the answer that is attached below, for the last row in the blue table, for v1 in the set of adjacent colours, they have (2,3,4) but v1 is adjacent to v2,v6,v7 and **v3** so shouldn't the set of adjacent colours be (1,2,3,4) because v3 is given colour 1 and so the colour chosen for v1 should be 5. I just wanted to know if this is an error in the mark scheme or just me missing something here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are correct, so far as I can see.